# How to create and run ASM Dll in VS 2017 (WPF aplication)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assembly, x86-64, dllimport

I want to create an ASM DLL in Visual studio 2017 to use it (invoke the function write in asm) in existing c# project. The DLL will be using 64-bit code. 
It will be very helpful if someone describes how to create this kind of DLL file and wrap it into a c# project to invoke a function.

Comment: If this is for [How to multiply \_\_m128i register by float factor using SSE?](//stackoverflow.com/q/59107162), I'm pretty sure C# has intrinsics for SSE instructions that you could use to implement this without a DLL call.

Comment: Yes I know that but you must implement using the NuGet tool a special framework (I tested it before). Anyway I want to create a asm dll because I have to compare the execution time in two cases:  first when I use the simd instructions in cpp dll and second in asm dll.